# How do I install the itertools package?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I wanted to try out the `permutations` function from the `itertools` module. But I keep getting the following error everytime I try to implement it:

*code:*

```
from itertools import permutations

txt=permutations('SKIN')
print(txt)
```

*output:*

```
<itertools.permutations object at 0x7fee48665950>
```

I tried using the command `pip install itertools` on my command prompt but I keep getting the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement itertools (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for itertools
```

How do I install the package?

Comment: This output is not an error.  It correctly returns the permutation object.  If you want to use the iterator, try:  `for x in txt: print(x)`.

Answer (score 10):

itertools is a built-in module no need to install it:

```
Help on module itertools:

NAME
    itertools - Functional tools for creating and using iterators.

FILE
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertoolsmodu
```

`permutations(<iterable>)` returns a generator which yields successive r length permutations of elements in the iterable:

```
>>> type(txt)
<type 'itertools.permutations'>

>>> dir(txt)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'next']
```

List of desired permutations:

```
list_perms = [ "".join(i) for i in permutations("SKIN")]

# ['SKIN', 'SKNI', 'SIKN', 'SINK', 'SNKI', 'SNIK', 'KSIN', 'KSNI', 'KISN', 'KINS', 'KNSI', 'KNIS', 'ISKN', 'ISNK', 'IKSN', 'IKNS', 'INSK', 'INKS', 'NSKI', 'NSIK', 'NKSI', 'NKIS', 'NISK', 'NIKS']
```

Answer (score 3):

`permutations()` returns an object, converting it to list will do the job.

```
from itertools import permutations

txt=list(permutations('SKIN'))
t = [''.join(i) for i in txt]
print(t)
```

Comment: I want the output to be: `['KINS','SINK',....]` instead of `[('K','I','N','S'),('S','I','N','K'),...]`.

Answer (score 2):

- [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#) is a built-in module in python and does not need to be installed separately.
- `<itertools.permutations object at 0x7fee48665950>` is not an error. It is a [`iterator`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.asp). In order to get its content it has to be converted to list.

Possible solution is the following:

```
from itertools import permutations

txt = ["".join(_) for _ in permutations('SKIN')]

print(txt)
```

Prints

```
['SKIN', 'SKNI', 'SIKN', 'SINK', 'SNKI', 'SNIK', 'KSIN', 'KSNI', 'KISN', 'KINS', 'KNSI', 'KNIS', 'ISKN', 'ISNK', 'IKSN', 'IKNS', 'INSK', 'INKS', 'NSKI', 'NSIK', 'NKSI', 'NKIS', 'NISK', 'NIKS']
```

Answer (score 0):

It works as suspected. The `permutations` is a generator that you can iterate over.

```
from itertools import permutations

txt=permutations('SKIN')
print(txt)

for single_permutation in txt:
    print(single_permutation)
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use new version, more-intertools instead.

> ```
> pip install more-itertools
> ```